# Browser-less server-side websockets client in Azure

Tags: azure, websocket

I have an azure static web app that gets data via azure functions written in javascript.

I would like to subscribe to external data push services using wss websockets. The socket may be open for up to 24 hours. I thought, having read some answers on SO that I might be able to do this using durable functions but it appears that it isn't possible.

Almost all examples of using websockets in azure I've seen create a server, eg with SignalR, and communicate with the browser.

This helps. It shows how to build a server-side websockets client in a webjob

https://mikewaniewski.wordpress.com/2015/06/14/websocket-client-as-azure-webjob/

but as it is from 2015 I wondered if there more recent technologies available to do the same thing? Before I go about setting all that up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, what did you end up using?

Comment: Hi, what I wanted to do isn't possible with Azure functions including durable functions because even then the function still goes to sleep after a certain amount of time has elapsed. [still editing this comment, pressed enter by mistake]

Comment: COuldn't finish editing my comment went over 5 minutes.... I combined functions with an Azure serveless Signalr hub for client connections. I solved my issue by using a combination of ftp, event grid and queue storage via on-premise components to get updates to the signalr hub for distribution as needed  I don't remember exact details ottomh. Ftp was incidental, just a push service providing similar data to the wss service I originally intended to use.